# JSP error issue in java

Tags: java, jsp

I have written a java `servlet` for a simple ebookshop and for some reason I don't understand why it does not compile. Below I pasted the part of the code that gives me the error:

```
public void int(ServletConfig conf) throws ServletException {
        super.init(conf);
}
```

The errors that occur are shown below:

1. `<identifier> expected -> (public void ^int(Servlet..... )...)`
2. `'(' expected -> piblic void **i**nt`
3. `illegal start of type -> public void int**(**Servlet....`
4. `';' expected -> public void int(ServletConfig^conf)...`
5. `<identifier> expected -> public void int(ServletConfig conf**)**...`
6. `illegal start of type -> public void int(ServletConfig conf) **throws**....`
7. `';' expected -> public void int(ServletConfig conf) throws ServletException^`

I don't really get it, this is supposed to work. If needed I will post the whole source file.

Any advise will do.

Comment: please post whole source file

Comment: @shreyanshjogi It isn't needed, the error is clear.

Comment: @Manolis Tsilikidis as I know it's not recommended to override init method with arguments. If you need to do something before servlet starts working override init method without arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public void **init**(ServletConfig conf) throws ServletException {
        super.init(conf);
}
```

It should be init, not int. You are calling init method of the super class from this init method.

This is one of the ways you get access to ServletConfig object in your servlet.

Other way you can do is by calling

```
ServletConfig conf = getServletConfig();
```

init method are called when servlet instance is loaded.

Comment: That was the problem, thanks. I am really new to JSP and just trying to make a code fragment I found to work. Now I have another problem. I compile and it throws an error again but it is asociated with "javax.servlet package". How can I compile it and add the related lib to the compilation? I try with the "-cp ;.(library's directory)" but it does not work... – Manolis Tsilikidis just now edit

Answer (score 2):

public void int cant be done choose either void or int; you should rename the methods name because int is a preserved word

Comment: @JoopEggen init is problematic, it is used in many complex objects and hes dealing with servlets, so hell use init a lot; a self-given-name would be wise imo

Comment: anyway, if that answered your question id like to get the 'Accepted' manolis, thanks.

Comment: A hint for the name is the call to `super.init(conf)`.

Comment: @JoopEggen oh, didnt see it till now, guess my brain made init to int after the first int. +1. anyhow, as Aleksei said above it is problematic to make init.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use keywords like `int` as identifiers in Java . This is specific to all code in Java. I guess you are trying to override the `init(ServletConfig)` method :

```
public void init(ServletConfig conf) throws ServletException {
    super.init(conf);
}
```

This is OK for learning purpose , but you should ideally override the no-arg [init()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/servlet/GenericServlet.html#init%28%29) in your Servlet lest you do something which makes the Servlet lifecycle go haywire. Don't override `init(ServletConfig)` unless it is absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 0):

when you define your method like

```
public void int(ServletConfig conf)
```

**public** : accesibility

**void** : return type

**int** : method name

**ServletConfig** : type of parameter the method accepts

**conf** : the parameter passed

now there will be nothing wrong and the method works perfectly

but java has reserved keywords which can not be used for any other purposes

in your case **int** , you are using this as the method name ,

but **int** is a reserved keyboard for defining variable of type int

further speaking

in your servlet life cycle

you have three methods ,

1 : init

2 : service

3 : destroy

clearly you are trying to initialize your servlet calling the init method

the erro you are facing is a simply TYPO error ,

simply rename your initilize method from **int** to **init**